# Trying to prove an inequality for a solution using the Variation of Constants Formula

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

I am working on the following problem

Let A be a constant matrix and 
\begin{align} 
\dot{x}=Ax+e(t) && x(0)=x_0
\end{align}

Such that $e(t)$ is continuous we want to show that for $a > \max_i Re(\lambda_i)$ where $\{\lambda\}_{j=1}^n$ are the eigenvalues of $A$, the following holds

\begin{align*} 
||x(t)|| \leq K e^{at} ( ||x_0||+ \int _0^t e^{-a s}||e(s)||ds)
\end{align*} 
For some number $K$

As a hint we are given the Variation of Constants Formula:

\begin{align*} 
x(t)=\phi(t)\phi^{-1}(0)x_0+\phi(t)\int _o^t \phi^{-1}(s)e(s) ds
\end{align*} 
Where $\phi(t)$ is the fundamental matrix of $\dot{x}=Ax+e(t)$.

What I know is that we have proved this same thorem for Homogenoues i.e. for 
\begin{align} 
\dot{x}=Ax && x(0)=x_0
\end{align} 
then 
\begin{align*} 
||x(t)|| \leq K e^{at}
\end{align*}

How we did that proof was buy using Jordan decomposition saying that we can write the matrix $A= T^{-1} J T$ then $x(t)= e^{\lambda t}x_0$ then observed that $e^{At}= T^{-1} e^{Jt} T$ where J is a jordan Block matrix. In that case life was easy, because of properties of the decomposition. I was originally trying to modify the class proof, but it fails because I cannot do the same becasue of the $e(t)$. Can someone guide me with the idea of the proof.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the idea by looking at the solution of a first-order linear differential equation
$$\frac{dx(t)}{dt}=ax(t)+u(t)$$
Which is:
$$x(t)=e^{at}\left(\int_0^te^{-as}u(s)ds+C\right)$$
I replaced $e(t)$ with $u(t)$ because it might have been confused with $e$.

So your system has a closed-form solution:
$$\begin{align}x(t)&=\Phi(t)\left(\int_0^t \Phi^{-1}(s)u(s)ds+\Phi^{-1}(0)x(0)\right)\\&=\int_0^t\Phi(t)\Phi^{-1}(s)u(s)ds+\Phi(t)\Phi^{-1}(0)x(0)
\\&=\int_0^t\Phi(t-s)u(s)ds+\Phi(t)x(0)
\end{align}$$
Hence regarding the triangle inequality:
$$\begin{align}
\lVert x(t)\rVert &=\lVert\int_0^t\Phi(t-s)u(s)ds+\Phi(t)x(0)\rVert\\
&\le\lVert\Phi(t)\rVert\cdot\lVert x(0)\rVert+\int_0^t\lVert\Phi(t-s)\rVert\cdot\lVert u(s)\rVert
ds
\end{align}$$

Now it is sufficient to prove that $\lVert\Phi(t-s)\rVert<e^{a(t-s)}$ for $0\le s\le t$, which seems straightforward according to the Jordan canonical form.

Comment: Can you please clarify the last two lines. I am not sure how you can say that  $\int ||\Phi||||\Phi ^{-1}||\leq \int ||\Phi \Phi^{-1}||$. Also the last line does not make sense to me.

Comment: @Gidy : I fixed a silly mistake. Note that $\Phi(t)=e^{At}$, then $\Phi(-t)=e^{-At}$